# Переопределить значение в функции, в библиотеке

Tags: python, opencv

я использую [библиотеку](https://github.com/nalepae/bounding-box) для рисования ограничивающих рамок:

```
from bounding_box import bounding_box as bb
bb.add(orig_image, int(box[0]), int(box[1]), int(box[2]), int(box[3]), f'{pred_classes[j]}-{score_percent}', config.BOX_COLOR)
```

Но дело в том, что **add** не принимает аргумент толщины. В исходном коде, в функции **add** есть такая строка:

```
def add(image, left, top, right, bottom, label=None, color=None):
    ...
    _cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), color, 2)
```

вот в этой строке, мне нужна 2-ка, которая и определяет толщину. Есть ли возможность на неё влиять, не переходя в исходный код библиотеки?

Comment: Никак не получится, кроме как в той библиотеке создать Issue на добавление этого параметра в `add`, а с вашей стороны временным решением будет использование этой же функции с передачей толщины

Comment: @gil9red спасибо) действительно, в `pull requests` была измененная ветка с возможностью изменять аргумент **thickness**